# Self-Host WCF single to many host routing

Tags: wcf, azure

UPDATE 2: Solved the first problem (note below) - reduced the complexity/scope.

NOTE: If migrating from self-hosting WCF services in Cloud Services to Service Fabric using HttpsBinding then you need to change the HostNameComparisonMode from Exact to StrongWildcard.

I have scenario where I have to open many (100+) WCF Service Hosts to receive callbacks from an external service. They have same Contract but with differing credentials (service certificates are unique to each of our customers).

I would like to know if it is possible to route all requests through a single Host/Router that could check the connecting clients expected service certificate and either a) spoof/ignore (preferably) the service certificate or forward the connection onto the correct host.

I want to avoid having to load hundreds of service hosts with different credentials (which are stored in a database) when the service fabric node first comes up so I don't receive traffic to a service that's not loaded yet.  Ideally I could load them when needed or not have to load them at all (spoofing certificate or something).

Looking for someone who is a lot savvier with WCF to shed some light on the possibilities. Thanks.

Comment: You are maybe looking in a [Routing Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423(v=vs.110).aspx) pattern?

Comment: Hmm interesting - this could work! I'll update if I get an solution up and running. Thanks

Comment: Updated the question with more detail